# Draw different Google Charts onClick, while changing src location with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a script that on page load draws some Google Charts in elements on the page. I also have a nav bar with months listed (M01, M02, M03...) in the text, that is supposed to draw different Charts for a month selected by the user. The scripts for each month are with the same "chart.js" name, but in a different folder (M01, M02, M03...). I'm failing to draw those charts onclick; ajax gets the right script, as I see it printed in the console, but I have no idea what I should do to execute it so that it draws different charts:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/GChart/M02/chart.js"></script>

    <script>
         function getChart(sender){
             var M = $(sender).text();
$.ajax({
    url: "https://globaldash.com/WebDB/assets/GChart/" + M + "/chart.js",
    dataType: "script",
    success: $.getScript( "https://globaldash.com/WebDB/assets/GChart/" + M + /chart.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    console.log( data ); // Data returned
    console.log( textStatus ); // Success
    console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
    console.log( "Load was performed." );
             })
            });
            };
    </script>
```

Comment: is "chart.js" your datatable?

Comment: Yes, it contains a drawChart() function and all the data for Google Charts.

Comment: Don't load it as a script, load it as JSON, and remove the non-JSON parts from the file. Then assign the JSON data to a variable on success, and pass it to a function that will use the variable data to draw the chart.

Comment: Like this: var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);